# weird bridge issue in KVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, tcpdump

on Centos 6.5 i have  a bridge **network** connected to eth4 and my virtual machine (**Centos6.5**) running on KVM  is also connected to that interface(vnet0)

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
network         8000.588d090ee15e       no              eth4
                                                        vnet0
```

VM is having an IP address 10.99.9.10 and host an ip address of 10.99.9.2 on **eth2**

VM can communicate outside,and its reachable from other Hosts,but **not from the Host** where its running.

pinged a **different Host** (10.99.9.3) from VM and it works fine tcpdump shows

**ping 10.99.9.3 -c 3**

tcpdump -n icmp

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
02:06:52.701448 IP 10.99.9.10 > 10.99.9.3: ICMP echo request, id 44807, seq 1, length 64
02:06:52.701896 IP 10.99.9.3 > 10.99.9.10: ICMP echo reply, id 44807, seq 1, length 64
02:06:53.701434 IP 10.99.9.10 > 10.99.9.3: ICMP echo request, id 44807, seq 2, length 64
02:06:53.701904 IP 10.99.9.3 > 10.99.9.10: ICMP echo reply, id 44807, seq 2, length 64
02:06:54.701117 IP 10.99.9.10 > 10.99.9.3: ICMP echo request, id 44807, seq 3, length 64
02:06:54.701489 IP 10.99.9.3 > 10.99.9.10: ICMP echo reply, id 44807, seq 3, length 64
```

But if i **ping the same host** 10.99.9.2

ping 10.99.9.2 -c 3

PING 10.99.9.2 (10.99.9.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

From 10.99.9.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

From 10.99.9.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

From 10.99.9.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.99.9.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3001ms
pipe 3

For me its strange that tcpdump -n icmp **shows nothing!!**

What could be the reason for this behavior,even if something blocks why isnt tcpdump not showing even ICMP request in tcpdump.

I only have one interface inside VM and tcpdump is performed on only available interface eth0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because your ARP may not be getting MAC of the host,since you are filtering only ICMP in tcpdump,it  will not show ARP lookups,remove ICMP and try

```
tcpdump -n arp
```

if you see only **ARP, Request who-has** and no reply then there is some other issue with your network and fix that,for now to see ICMP in tcpdump try editing arp cache,using

```
arp -s IP MAC
```

and verify by

```
arp -a
```

this wont fix your network issue but it might show ICMP in tcpdump